# How do I stop ReSharper starting a new line unnecessarily?

Tags: resharper

This has been bugging me since upgrading to ReSharper 8.0. If I have a line of text which is longer than the "Right margin (columns)" setting I now get this:

```
  TimeSpan.Parse(
                 RoleEnvironment.GetConfigurationSettingValue(
                                                              "InputQueueReadTimeout"),
```

ReSharper now starts a new line even when it doesn't help reduce the length of the line it is trying to shorten. This is just an example, but it happens all the time and often in cases where there is something else that is also wrapped, removing the need to break the line at all (in that case if I manually remove the line breaks afterwards then it doesn't try to insert them again!).

Is there a way to stop it doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uncheck the following option:

ReSharper | Options | Code Editing | C# | Formatting Style | Other | Align Multiline Constructs | First call arguments by "(".

Answer (score 0):

Try backing up all your personal / team / global resharper configuration files and then resetting them all back to defaults to see if that fixes your issue?

I haven't encountered this behavior in R# 8.x with the default settings, so I'm thinking that you have a local change somewhere that's causing this issue.

Once you do that you should be able to use a diff tool to compare yours and the default configs to isolate the configuration combinations that's causing it.